# Auto increment for loop with multiple rows from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, auto-increment

I have a mysql query that pulls a variable from database and repeats some html based on the number of the variable. It then assigns an ID to a radio button based on an auto increment.

This works fine when only one row is returned by the query, however when 2 rows are returned it will assign ID 0 to 2 lots of radio buttons then assign 1, 2, 3 etc

```
<?php
$roster_infantry_raw = tep_db_query("select * from " . $table . " where name = '" . $_GET['model'] . "'");
while ($infantry = tep_db_fetch_array($roster_infantry_raw)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < (int) $infantry['count_min']; $i++) {
?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">
        <?php echo tep_draw_radio_field('weapon1[' . $i . ']', 'weapon1', true); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate (Show us the query, the html, the expected result)

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: where is radio button code

Comment: Start `$i` at 1 instead of 0, and change your check from `<` to `<=`